# 2007 Chinese National Olympiad day 1 P3

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

I have been trying to solve the problem but have really struggled to wrap my head around it. Even reading the solution I cannot get past the first claims with understanding. I have spent several days on it (though not thinking about it all of the time) and would really really appreciate it if someone could offer a detailedly explained solution that someone without strong olympiad background can follow, or if someone could even just explain the key insights of the solution to me would be super helpful.

I really hope someone can answer this soon as it has been following me for so many days and I really want to know how to approach the problem...! Many thanks in advance.

[Problem description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epqhn.jpg):

> Let $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{11}$ be $11$ distinct positive integers with their sum less than $2007$, and write the numbers $1,2,\dots,2007$ on a blackboard. Now we define a group of $22$ ordered operations:
>
> The $i$th operation is to take any number on the blackboard, and then add $a_i$ to it, if $1\le i\le11$ or minus $a_{i-11}$ from it, if $12\le i\le22$.
>
> If the final result after such a group of operations is an even permutation of $1,2,\dots,2007$, then we call it a "good" group; if the result is an odd permutation of $1,2,\dots,2007$, then we call it a "second good" group.
>
> Our question is: Which is greater? The number of "good" groups or that of "second good" groups? And by how many more?
>
> (Remark: Suppose $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ is a permutation of $1,2,\dots,n$. We call it an even permutation if $\prod_\limits{i>j}\left(x_i-x_j\right)>0$, and otherwise an odd permutation.)

Solutions:
[Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waC1J.png)
[Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJn6j.png) (Taken from the book *Mathematical Olympiads in China (2007-2008): Problems and Solutions* edited by Xiong Bin and Lee Peng Yee)

Edit: To clarify the parts of the solution which I don't understand, why would exchanging the $i$th and $j$th operations of the group not result in a change in $f$? And what is the rationale behind only needing to prove that the number of "good" and "second good" groups with property $P$ are the same? This is where I am currently blocked in understanding the solution.

Comment: Can you type out the question and solution? I did not downvote your post, but in your current state with the questions and solutions attached as an image, your question is bound to attract downvotes. Besides, please clarify exactly what part of the solution you do not understand.

Comment: @IraeVid Thank you for point that out to me. Apologies that I am unable to type out the question and solutions as I currently do not know LaTeX and am new to StackExchange... I have edited the question with clarifications.

Comment: Personally, although your current posting violates the protocol of including a link to another webpage, and also violates the protocol of using an image to express math, I am **very happy** with your presentation of the problem.  Since you **also** used [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), I regard this presentation as a rare exception to the MathSE protocol.  Often a poster will miswrite/misinterpret a problem or leave out pertinent details.  This causes confusion.  By including the link, you allow MathSE reviewers to verify your presentation.  ...see next comment

Comment: Further, I feel that your presentation *reads better* with the **problem image** on a separate webpage, rather than embedded in the posting.  I ask other MathSE reviewers to therefore leave the *problem presentation*, including the link to another webpage, **as is**.

Comment: To the OP (i.e. original poster).  On the one hand, since you haven't *shown work*, many MathSE reviewers will feel that you posting deserves to be downvoted.  See for example [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).  Not only do I disagree with such a reaction to this posting, I personally upvoted your posting.  ...see next comment

Comment: Re my previous comments, I regard the presentation of both the question and answer, including the linked *math-images* as optimal.  That is, the posting *reads* well.  Further, you very carefully explained your precise questions.  Also, the nature of this Olympiad problem is such that I feel that it is *beating a dead horse* to ask you to *show work* here.

Comment: To the OP : By the way - your posting has already received two **votes to close**.  If it receives three more, then the posting will be (at least temporarily) closed, which prevents the posting from receiving answers.  So, obviously, at least two (other) MathSE reviewers disagree with my overall reaction.  For what it's worth, I personally can't post an answer because this problem is out of my expertise.  I would have to study the problem for hours, if not days, to be able to answer it. ...see next comment

Comment: If the problem does get closed, (only) then, I suggest following the protocol article that I linked to (except the part about managing *math images*).  This signifies  providing as many pertinent details as possible, including your Math education.  It also signifies striving to show work in excruciating detail, in as well organized a manner as possible.  **Again**, I advise this **only if** the posting is closed before you receive an answer.  If you go this route, after the posting is closed, then address a comment to @user2661923, notifying me that you edited the posting.  ...see next comment

Comment: Then, I will *lobby* to have the question re-opened.